# MS Project Calendar Mismatch between Server and Client

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, ms-project-2016

we use MS Project Professional, connected to Project Server 2016.

Our standard working times on the server calendar are as follows:

Mon 8.00 - 12.00, 13.00 - 16.30;
Tues 8.00 - 12.00, 13.00 - 16.30;
Wed 8.00 - 12.00, 13.00 - 16.30;
Thurs 8.00 - 12.00, 13.00 - 16.30;
Fri 8.00 - 12.00, 13.00 - 16.00

This gives us a 37 hour working week, with the slightly early finish on a Friday.

On the client side I am unable to find a method which will account for the early finish on a Friday.

In Project Options, Schedule I have the following settings:

Default Start Time: 8.00
Default End Time: 16.30
Hours per day: 7.5
Hours per week: 37
Days per month: 20

Within my organisation we tend to plan (despite my attempts to change this behaviour amongst our Project Managers) by Duration. So, if we have a task beginning on a Monday at 8.00 and it is planned for 5 days MS Project will show the task as finishing at 8.30 the following Monday, rather than 16.00 on the Friday.

Whilst, on the surface, this is fairly insignificant, many of our projects span 4 or 5 years so these additional 1/2 hours quickly add up and push the overall project end date out quite significantly.

I have tried many different settings in the client side options but have not yet found a method to resolve this:

I've tried the following:

Hours per day: 7.4
Hours per week: 37

Hours per day: 7.5
Hours per week: 37.5

and various other combinations.

I have also tried being more granular with the tasks and using the finish time in addition to start date but this then results in very odd looking durations which cause our customers great confusion.

Has anyone else run into a problem of this nature and did you manage to come up with a workaround?

Comment: Unless the hour component of a date is super important, can you change the server calendar so that Friday is the same as the other days and then set hours per day to 7.5? With projects that span years, it would seem that the 30 minutes on Friday that you don't work would be insignificant.

Comment: @RachelHettinger thanks for the response, that would be my preference but unfortunately, the server calendar is linked into our SAP system which is used to drive MRP so I'm told I can't do that (apparently that 30 min is very important on that side of the business!)

Comment: Sounds like your best option is to do 7.4 hours per day and have all durations in days or partial days rather than hours. Perhaps then the only odd part will be the times which are easily hidden from view. Or you could use a formula in Date1 & Date2 to display Start/Finish dates with custom formatting (maybe round to the nearest hour?)  Don't forget to update the base calendars with the 7.4 hour work day.

Comment: @RachelHettinger I had asked the Project Manager to try using 7.4 hours but I neglected to request they only use full or partial days, I will try that and see how they get on. Thank you Rachel. Will let you know if that works.